# Callbacks in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an async function

```
function(word,callback)
{
  setTimeout(3000, function()
  {
      console.log("waiting");
  }
  callback(null, word);
}

function f2 (err, result){
  console.log(result);
}
```

What is the result?
How does `callback` know I am referring to `f2`?

Answer (score 1):

There is no result. That code won't even compile.

Even if you fix the syntax errors, you never call any functions.

Assuming you fixed all of that, it would know that you were referring to `f2` because you would be explicitly passing it as the second argument.

```
function my_function_that_accepts_a_callback (word, callback) {
    setTimeout(3000, function() {
            console.log("waiting");
        }
        callback(null, word);
    }
}

function f2(err, result) {
    console.log(result);
}

my_function_that_accepts_a_callback("this is a word", f2);
```

Comment: Yes this is what I meant. Just a question: Does callback(null, word) run after the timeout or before?  Let me know if I am right: Due to async nature, the callback(null, word) would run before set timeout finishes. True?